# Selenium Reporting in XUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, reporting

**Senario:**

Creating a test with the XUnit framework.

```
    [Theory]
    [classData(typeof(TestdateObjectRepo))]
    public void TestMethod1(TestDateObject testdata)
    {
        //Arrange 
        ... Arrange somthing to prep the Test;
        //Act
        bool result = Application.UIKeywords().Login(testdata);
        //Assert is done with FluentAssertion
        result.Should().BeTrue();
    }
```

as fixture I us [Theory] and [classData] because I create testdata Objects from different sources.

In addition to DDT I use a Keyword Architecture. Each Keyword is a collection of Selenium actions.
For example the keyword Login is a collection of the action

click.Usernametextbox

SendKeys.UsernameTextbox(testdata.Username)

click.PasswordTextbox

SendKeys.PasswordTextbox(testdata.Username)

click.LoginButton

FindElement(ThisElementConfirmsThatLoginWasSuccessful)

You get the idea.

**Problem:**

I want to implement instant Reporting -> Restcall to jira's xray. Which would not be a problem as long as the testcase fails within the assert section of the test.
However. 
How can I catch an exception (without try/catch around the keywords there are around 100-150 keywords) that is thrown by an action in a keyword. There is no testcontext deliverd by xUnit as soon as the test calls it's "after" Method. 
After Methode in "" because in Xunit there is no AfterMethod per definition only an Dispose class which is called after every test.

I know that this is rather a Global q and not really a Test-Automation related q but I'm stuck with that one. 
A hint or maybe a best practice tip would be appriciated.

Thanks :-)